# AWS Lambda NodeJS writing to S3 behaves differently on local and sever

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I created a NodeJS Lambda function with Serverless. It reads from a DynamoDB table and writes the data to a S3 bucket.

Here's my `handler.js`: (showing the affected function):

```
module.exports.exportContactsByClientID = (event, context, callback) => {
  // const id = event.pathParameters.id.toLowerCase();
  const id= 'mkh';
  
  const params = {
    TableName: contactsTable,
    IndexName: "client_code-created_at_local-index",
    KeyConditionExpression: "client_code = :v_ID",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":v_ID": id,
    },
    ProjectionExpression: "client_code, created_at, contact_name, age, phone, email, dsr_ratio, max_eligibility, selected_banks"
  };

return db.query(params)
.promise()
.then((res) => {
  // console.log(res);
  const items = res.Items;
  // Headers + Columns
  worksheet.cell(1, 1).string('Client').style({font: {bold: true}});
  worksheet.cell(1, 2).string('Name').style({font: {bold: true}});
  worksheet.cell(1, 3).string('Age').style({font: {bold: true}});
  worksheet.cell(1, 4).string('Email').style({font: {bold: true}});
  worksheet.cell(1, 5).string('Phone').style({font: {bold: true}});
  worksheet.cell(1, 6).string('DSR Ratio').style({font: {bold: true}});
  worksheet.cell(1, 7).string('Max Eligibility').style({font: {bold: true}});
  // Rows
  // items.sort((a, b) => (a.date > b.date) ? -1 : 1);
  items.forEach((item, i) => {
    console.log(item.contact_name);
    worksheet.cell(i + 2, 1).string(item.client_code);
    worksheet.cell(i + 2, 2).string(item.contact_name);
    worksheet.cell(i + 2, 3).string(item.age);
    worksheet.cell(i + 2, 4).string(item.email);
    worksheet.cell(i + 2, 5).string(item.phone);
    worksheet.cell(i + 2, 6).string(item.dsr_ratio);
    worksheet.cell(i + 2, 7).string(item.max_eligibility);
  });
  console.log(contactsBucket);
  console.log(id);
  workbook.writeToBuffer().then(buffer => {
    console.log('inside writetoubgger')
    var params = {
      Bucket: contactsBucket,
      Key: `contacts/mkh.xlsx`,
      Body: buffer,
      ACL: 'public-read'
    }
    S3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack);
      } else {
        // callback(null, response(200, res));
        callback(null, response(200, res));
      }
    });
  })
})
.catch((err) => callback(null, response(err.statusCode, err)));
};
```

My `serverless.yml`:

```
service: mhub-dsr-calculator-api

plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-include-dependencies

package:
  exclude:
    - node_modules/**

custom:
  allowed-headers:
      - Content-Type
      - Authorization
      - X-Api-Token
      - X-Origin
      - X-Amz-Date
      - X-Amz-Security-Token
  settings:
    CONTACTS_TABLE: dsrcalculator-contacts-dev
    CONTACTS_BUCKET: mhub-dsrcalculator-contacts

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  environment: ${self:custom.settings}
  region: ap-southeast-1 
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - dynamodb:DescribeTable
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
        - dynamodb:Query
      Resource:
        - "arn:aws:dynamodb:${self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:custom.settings.CONTACTS_TABLE}"
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - dynamodb:Query
      Resource:
        - "arn:aws:dynamodb:${self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:custom.settings.CONTACTS_TABLE}/index/client_code-created_at_local-index"
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
       - "s3:*"
      Resource: 
       - "arn:aws:s3:::${self:custom.settings.CONTACTS_BUCKET}/*"

functions:
  createPost:
    handler: handler.createContact
    events:
    - http:
        path: /contact
        method: post
        cors: true
  updatePost:
    handler: handler.updateContact
    events:
    - http:
        path: /contact/{id}
        method: put
        cors: true
  getAllPosts:
    handler: handler.getAllContacts
    events:
    - http:
        path: /contacts
        method: get
        cors: true
  getContactsByClientID:
    handler: handler.getContactsByClientID
    events:
    - http:
        path: /contacts/{id}
        method: get
        cors: true
  exportContactsByClientID:
    handler: handler.exportContactsByClientID
    events:
    - http:
        path: /export/{id}
        method: get
        cors: true

resources:
  Resources:
    PostsTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: "id"
          AttributeType: "S"
        - AttributeName: "client_code"
          AttributeType: "S"
        - AttributeName: "created_at_local"
          AttributeType: "S"
        KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: "id"
          KeyType: "HASH"
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        TableName: ${self:custom.settings.CONTACTS_TABLE}
```

I get the following output when I invoke the function locally (with `serverless invoke local -f exportContactsByClientID`) where 'mhub-dsrcalculator-contacts' is the bucket name, 'mkh' is the id and 'inside writetoubgger' indicates the code inside `workbook.writeToBuffer` ran.

```
mhub-dsrcalculator-contacts
mkh
inside writetoubgger
```

A file on S3 bucket is created successfully.

However when I deploy this and test, though it runs to succession the code is not entering into 'workbook.writeToBuffer' as we can see below.

```
2020-06-22T11:23:22.945Z    1ce59a7b-98e4-4c9e-8736-ec7c162c4759    INFO    mhub-dsrcalculator-contacts
2020-06-22T11:23:22.945Z    1ce59a7b-98e4-4c9e-8736-ec7c162c4759    INFO    mkh
END RequestId: 1ce59a7b-98e4-4c9e-8736-ec7c162c4759
```

Why is this happening? Any guidance will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outer promise is finishing without waiting the `writeToBuffer` promise.

Try changing:

```
workbook.writeToBuffer().then(...
```

To:

```
return workbook.writeToBuffer().then(...
```

You should do the same to the S3 upload call:

```
return S3.upload(params).promise().then(data => {
        callback(null, response(200, res));
});
```

I would also recommend you rewrite your code using the `async` / `await` syntax, so it is easier to read and understand.

Comment: May I ask - now it works when invoked from AWS but when I try it on the browser or Postman it fails with '"Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"'.

Comment: On AWS my test event is defined as: {
  "pathParameters": {
    "id": "ijm"
  }
} Am I not specifying it correctly in my code with const id = event.pathParameters.id.toLowerCase(); ?

Comment: You should check for an empty `event.pathParameters`.

Comment: A `console.log(event)` should help you debug this issue.

Comment: I rewrote the code with async/await like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62568043/calling-dydnamodb-query-and-then-writing-result-to-s3-bucket-how-to-simplify-th/62569121#62569121 (the answer). Appreciate your feedback if it's okay or can be further improved.